# How to split and count sms messages from file in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv, sms-gateway

I have problem that my sms messages are imported with csv, then it is checked if number is ok and how long sms is. My problem is that if text messages is longer then 160 it still enters 1 in databse. But it should start counting, if it is less or equal than 160, it is 1 messages, if it is more than 160 but less or equal than 320 it is two messages and if it is more then it is 3 messages.
Page code is here:

```
<?php
$link = @mysql_connect("localhost", "admin", "") or die("Error: Database offline.");
mysql_select_db("database", $link);
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8' ", $link);

function detect_type($smstext) {
$type = 0;
$dec_codes = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($smstext); $i++) {
    $symbol = substr($smstext,$i,1);
    if (!in_array(ord($symbol), $dec_codes)) { $type = 1; }
}
return $type;       
}
$result_array = array();
$unic_numbers = array();
$fp = file_get_contents($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']);
$fp = str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $fp);
$fp = str_replace("\r", "\n", $fp);
$fp  = str_replace("\t", "", $fp);  
$rows = explode("\n", $fp);             
$imported_rows = 0;
$duplicate_rows = 0;
$error_rows = 0;
$long_rows = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($rows); $i++) {    
$data = explode(";", $rows[$i]);
$data[1] = sms_formatNumbers($data[1]); // formating number
$userid = 78;
    if(strlen($data[1]) > 9){ 
        if($unic_numbers[$data[1]] != true ){  // unic number check
            $unic_numbers[$data[1]] = true;
            $imported_rows++;
            $fullSMS =  iconv("ISO-8859-1","UTF-8", trim($data[2])." ".trim($data[3])." ".trim($data[4]));
            if(strlen($fullSMS) > 164){
                $long_rows++;
            }           
    if($_POST['action'] == 'send'){                 
            // SMS TEXT 
            $smstext = str_replace("õ", "ò", $fullSMS);
            $smstext = str_replace("Õ", "ò", $smstext);
            $type = detect_type($smstext);                  
            // servicegroup             
            $char2 = substr($data[1], 0, 2);
            $char3 = substr($data[1], 0, 3);                                                                    
            $c1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM zone_info WHERE country_code = '".$char2."'", $link);
            $c2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM zone_info WHERE country_code = '".$char3."'", $link);
            if (mysql_num_rows($c1) == 1) {
                $r = mysql_fetch_array($c1);
                $price = $r['price'];
                $z = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM zone WHERE id = ".$r['up']."", $link);
                $zone = mysql_fetch_array($z);
                $zone_id = $zone['id'];
                $servicegroup = $zone['servicegroup'];
            } else if (mysql_num_rows($c2) == 1) {
                $r = mysql_fetch_array($c2);
                $price = $r['price'];
                $z = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM zone WHERE id = ".$r['up']."", $link);
                $zone = mysql_fetch_array($z);
                $zone_id = $zone['id'];
                $servicegroup = $zone['servicegroup'];
            }   
            require_once("../scripts/number.class.php");
            $receiver = "00".$data[1];      
            $obj = new NumberClass($receiver);
            $operator = $obj -> operator_code;
            $country = $obj -> code;
            $operator_name = $obj -> operator_name;             
        if(strlen($operator) > 0) {
        $er = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM zone_exception WHERE country = ".$country." AND operator = ".$operator."", $link);
        if (mysql_num_rows($er) == 1) {
            $erand = mysql_fetch_array($er);
            $price = $erand['price'];
            $servicegroup = $erand['servicegroup'];                                                         
        }
    } else $operator_name = "-";
    if ($operator_name == "-") { $servicegroup = $servicegroup; }
    else {
        if ($operator_name == " First Operator") $servicegroup = "90";
        else if ($operator_name == "Second Operator") $servicegroup = "91";
        else if ($operator_name == "Third Operator") $servicegroup = "92";
        else $servicegroup = $servicegroup;
    }
    require_once("../core/init.mini.inc.php");      
    $servicegroup = UserBasedRerouting($receiver, $userid, $operator_name, $servicegroup);                  
            $client_type ='corporative';
            $sender = $data[0];             
            $zone_id = 11;
            $client_sms_id = '0';
            $client_want_report = '0';
            $client_report_url = '';
            $amount = 1;
            $dt_delaysend = '1970-01-01 00:00:00';
            $SMSsent = 0;
            $SMStotal = 1;
            $smstext_old = $smstext;            
            while($SMSsent < $SMStotal){    
        $sql = mysql_query("insert into sms_queue (user_id,client_type,dt_entered,sender,receiver,operator,smstext,sms_type,zone_id,client_sms_id,client_want_report,client_report_url,sms_price,amount,servicegroup,dt_delaysend) values ('$userid','$client_type','".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."','$sender','$receiver','$operator_name','$smstext',0,'$zone_id','$client_sms_id','$client_want_report','$client_report_url','$price','$amount','$servicegroup','$dt_delaysend')", $link);
                $SMSsent++;
            }               
    }
        }else{
            $duplicate_rows ++;
        }

    }else{
        $error_rows++;
    }
}
$result_array['success'] = true;
$result_array['long_sms'] = $long_rows;
$result_array['send_sms'] = $imported_rows;
$result_array['error_sms'] = $error_rows;
$result_array['duplicate_sms'] = $duplicate_rows;
$result_array['action'] = $_POST['action']; 
echo json_encode($result_array);        
function sms_formatNumbers($number){    
$number = (int)$number; 

$start_code = (int)substr($number,0,4);
if($start_code < 3780 or $start_code == 3785 or $start_code > 3789){
    return $number;
}else{
    return '';
}
}
?>
```

Can someone help me out with that?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if(strlen($fullSMS) > 164){
       $long_rows = ceil(strlen($fullSMS)/160);
}
```

instead of

```
if(strlen($fullSMS) > 164){
        $long_rows++;
}
```